# Can't update app registered in Microsoft Application Registration Portal

Tags: onedrive

I have an already registered app in the site https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.  I want to add another redirect URL but when I tried saving I get this error:

There's a temporary problem
There's a temporary problem with the service. Please try again. If you continue to get this message, try again later.

I have also tried using a different browser and clearing my cache but I still get the error.

I also tried registering a new app and I still get the same error. I have been getting the error for several days now and I was wondering if anybody knows a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the support team? Seems like an issue on their end imo.

Comment: Is the URL you are wanting to add in the same root domain as the original URL? There are restrictions on the redirect URLs, and perhaps the error being surfaced is a generic error instead of a more specific error about the actual cause? AFAIK, redirect URLs must be in the same root domain (foo.bar.com, baz.bar.com is allowed, but not foo.com and bar.com)

Comment: @RyanGregg I can add the url just fine, it's when I save the changes that I get the error

Comment: @AzizSaleh Yeah I did and they told me that since I dont have an MS developer account they can't help me.  I need to get a developer account, but the app I am working on will only be internal and will never be published in any MS stores.

Answer (score 0):

There are several restrictions on the format of the redirect URI that is allowed

Currently, apps that are registered in the Application Registration Portal are restricted to a limited set of redirect URI values. The redirect URI for web apps and services must begin with the scheme https, and all redirect URI values must share a single DNS domain. For example, you cannot register a web app that has one of these redirect URIs:

```
https://login-east.contoso.com
https://login-west.contoso.com
```

The scenarios that are accepted are when the DNS name matches exactly. Examples:

```
https://login.contoso.com
https://login.contoso.com/new
https://new.login.contoso.com
```

See [all the v2.0 limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations)